# Scrollable parent div with scrollable children div

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a scrollable parent div with 2 children div that are also scrollable. How can I scroll div 2 on its own?

I have wrapped the 2 scrollable children div into `<div style={{ display: 'flex', overflow: 'scroll' }}>` and also added `overflow: 'scroll'` and set width into the children div but i can't scroll it on its own

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by individually adding the `overflow: scroll` to each div.

This may be helpful.
https://jsfiddle.net/obx362my/25/

Comment: Thank you. I also need the parent div to be scrollable. i.e `<div style="display: flex; width: 500px"> <div style="width: 400px; overflow: scroll" >child 1</div><div style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll" >child 2</div></div>`. In the jsfiddle only the children div are scrollable